# gdalwarp with DSM as DEM leaves shifted pixels in their original unshifted location

Tags: gdal, dem, gdalwarp, orthorectification

I'm trying to account for building parallax differences between images collected at different viewing angles. When I use a DSM created from VRICON data as my DEM source, I notice that building roof pixels are properly shifted to the correct location; however, they're also left in their original un-shifted position.  Does anyone know if there is a way to replace the original location of these pixels to no-data?

This is how I am calling gdalwarp.
gdalwarp -to RPC_DEM=vriconfile -co COMPRESS=LZW -co INTERLEAVE=BAND -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES -rpc -et 0 -overwrite -wo WRITE_FLUSH=YES -wo OPTIMIZE_SIZE=YES -multi -r near -dstnodata 0 -wm 1024 -of GTIFF -t_srs EPSG:4326 infile outfile

Example images attached.
[image: Severe Pixel Replication]
[image: Moderate Pixel Replication]